# How to remove module from kernel using -r or rmmod?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, video, kernel, kernel-modules

I have a card installed, which causing not to get ip address automatically using DHCP. So i need to remove that card completely for the moment. I tried as below but its not working how can i remove it?

```
$ lsmod | card
card   45555 2

$ modprobe -r card
FATAL: Module card is in use.

$ rmmod card
FATAL: Module card is in use.
```

Comment: `lsmod|card` is not the real command you gave I think. You missed the grep part pasting here possibly. So, is this output the whole one? I mean is there any other modules using card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to blacklist the driver that is being loaded:

```
sudo nano `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`
```

add the driver-name using following syntax:

```
blacklist driver-name
```

Alternatively,

Create a file '/etc/modprobe.d/[modulename].conf' containing 'blacklist [modulename]'.

Run `depmod -ae` as root

Recreate your initrd with `update-initramfs -u`

<sub>[source](http://wiki.debian.org/KernelModuleBlacklisting)</sub>

In the dim and distant past I seem to remember you can do this from Grub - not sure if this is still applicable in oneiric but you could try as one of your Grub boot options

```
modprobe.blacklist=kernel_module
```